# Deploy OVF Package Fails

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vsphere, virtualbox, vmware-vmdk, ovf

Using vSphere client I am trying to import a VM that was exported from VirtualBox.

I exported an `.ova` file from VirtualBox, I then used [VMVware OVF Tool](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/) to modify the file `.ova` and create the following three files;

- myVm.mf
- myVm.ovf
- myVm.vmdk

When importing initially I received the following error message;

> Unsupported hardware family “virtualbox-2.2”.

However I was able to resolve this by editing the `.ovf` file and generating a new Sha key using File [Checksum Integrity Verifier](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=11533).

Now when I try to import the VM the message I receive is;

> "Failed to deploy OVF package: file myVm.vmdk fails integrity check
>   and may have been corrupted during transfer"

Any ideas why, or what I can do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Why would you have to modify the OVA? That kind of defeats the entire purpose of OVA/OVF doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out I had to simply delete the `myVm.mf` file. It then worked no problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when an OVF image of a Virtual Appliance file is modified upon extraction.  This usually occurs when a virtual image is being extracted using WinZip.

Steps to deploy an OVF image properly:

Verify that you are using the supported platform.
Verify that the md5sum of the OVF image matches with the md5sum which is provided on the support site for that particular Virtual Appliance.
Create a folder on your local host.
Extract the virtual appliance on the created folder.
Remove the .mf file from the directory.
Import the OVF image now, and deploy it.